# Reading JSON each n second in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I need to repeatedly read a local JSON file to make a plot. This file changes each ***n*** seconds. Because the file changes, I use `$.getJSON()` and `setInterval()` to read the file every ***n*** seconds, but it doesn't work.

I watched the requests in *Network (Chrome Dev Tools)* and the file is read only 1 time. What could it be? The code that fetches the JSON from server follows:

```
$.getJSON('static/mediciones.json', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart : {
            events : {
                load : function() {
                    var series = this.series[0];

                    $.getJSON('static/mediciones2.json?'+ new Date().getTime(), function(data) {
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var lastKey = Object.keys(data).sort().reverse()[0];
                            console.log("ultimo" + lastKey);
                            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                                //console.log(value[0]);
                                series.addPoint([value[0], value[1]], true, true);
                            });
                        }, 10000);
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        //...
```

Comment: Please do include only the relevant code for the problem at hand... since you've diagnosed that request isn't being sent, that code alone would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the following code :

```
$.getJSON('static/mediciones2.json?'+ new Date().getTime(), function(data) {
    setInterval(function() {
        var lastKey = Object.keys(data).sort().reverse()[0];
        console.log("ultimo" + lastKey);
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            //console.log(value[0]);
            series.addPoint([value[0], value[1]], true, true);
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```

Clearly you are getting JSON file only once and onsuccess, you are parsing the same data after every 10 seconds.

You need to bring the setInterval out of getJSON.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON('static/mediciones2.json?'+ new Date().getTime(), function(data) {
        var lastKey = Object.keys(data).sort().reverse()[0];
        console.log("ultimo" + lastKey);
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            //console.log(value[0]);
            series.addPoint([value[0], value[1]], true, true);
        });
    });
}, 10000);
```

I didn't test this.

May be the following URLs will give more help on fixing this :

1. [HighCharts Demo - Dynamically Update Data](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update/)
2. [HighCharts Demo - Dynamically Update Data - JSFiddle](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update/)

Answer (score 0):

1. The code doesn't seem to be calling the function a second time.
2. The syntax for $.getJSON seems faulty. [See the docs here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

   jQuery.getJSON( url [, data ] [, success( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) ] )

Currently, you seem to be passing the callback in place of data (not sure how that's handled, better to be safe and pass a null). Also, note that the `[,data]` refers to data you are **sending to the server**, while the `sucess( data...` refers to the data **the server is responding with**.

Adapting that in your case...

```
load : function() {
    var series = this.series[0];
    $.getJSON('static/mediciones2.json?'+ new Date().getTime(), null, 
            function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var data = JSON.parse(responseData),
                lastKey = Object.keys(data).sort().reverse()[0];
            console.log("ultimo" + lastKey);
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                //console.log(value[0]);
                series.addPoint([value[0], value[1]], true, true);
            });
        });
    //Reload after 10seconds...
    setTimeout(this.load, 10000);
}
```

Note that your initial `$.getJSON()` shall also have to be changed - I've not done that. Also, a `setTimeout()` here is the general usage instead of `setInterval()`, since the function calls itself (and hence, every instance scheduling the next instance is sufficient). I changed it since your usage seemed to hint at a timeout rather than an interval.

Answer (score 0):

If json should be loaded each time, should be inside setInterval.